# How to read different configuration file based on option - python & command line

Tags: python

I have multiple configuration files and I want to read a different config file based on which option I type. For example if I type in the terminal

```
python test.py -60min
```

I want to read the python script to read the config file `'/home/matt/config_60min.ini'`

Similarly, `python test.py -30min` would read `'/home/matt/config_30min.ini'`

I'm not sure if this would be done using conditional logic within the script or with a simple option parser. Maybe there's a better way to go about it such as `python test.py -f 60min`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
import sys
config_path = '/home/matt/config_{}.ini'.format(sys.argv[1])
```

and run the script using:

```
python test.py 60min
```

If it gets more complicated than this, consider using the `argparse` library